# My employer wants me to work from the office against my doctor's orders

Tags: management, telecommute

I work from home in California now due to my medical issues. My doctor wanted me to be off all together but I can't afford it and he agreed to have me work from home. My company is continuously bullying me into coming back to work in the office or going back on disability. My productivity has not declined due to my working from home.

What irritates me is dishonest way they are dealing with me. When I asked my boss about the HR letter he said he will take care of it and that my work is not suffering from my working from home. Then I got another email from HR where they are stating that the requirement for me to work in the office comes from my boss.

How best can I address this with my employer?

Comment: This isn't a site that offers legal advice. Secondly, where are you in the world as I'm pretty sure this could vary from country to country a bit.

Comment: southern California

Comment: What is irritated is dishonest way they are dealing with me. When I asked my boss about HR letter he said he will take care of it and that my work is not suffering from me working from home. Then I got another email from HR where they are stating that the requirement for me to work from office comes from my boss

Comment: I'm not looking for legal advice.

Comment: Please edit the question. "Is their approach legal?" sounds a lot like asking for legal advice to my mind.

Comment: Being in CA, you likely have more employee rights than many other parts of the planet, but we really can't answer the question directly. I'd suggest calling a few employment lawyers and see if they can give you a free 5 minute summary of what your options are.

Comment: Also, HR is doing what HR does...which is usually very little. Boss tends to trump your doctor, so ultimately, this likely does turn into a legal question...you need a lawyer to trump HR.

Comment: Is there any written evidence of your boss saying he would take care of it and that you were equally productive at home?  These are the sorts of things you need to have ready if you talk to a lawyer.  Also a written communication from the doctor stating in writing that it's his medical opinion that you should be working from home.

Comment: Given the additional detail in the comments, I have updated the question to reflect that you are _not_ looking for legal advice.

Comment: If your doctors says you need to be not working and you cannot afford it, make a mental note and next time around vote for someone who changes this. Laws don't appear out of nowhere, humans made them, humans can change them.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:** Gather all your evidence for why you need to work at home and that it does not reduce your productivity and consider offering a compromise.

At this point you need to make a case to your boss and to HR as to *why* they should allow you to continue to work from home.  Evidence should include:

- A certificate from your doctor stating that in his *professional* opinion, you should be working from home rather than in an office
- Any written evidence of your employer saying that it was okay for you to work at home
- Any written evidence that your boss said that your productivity was not reduced from working at home.

To try to improve your chances, you could offer to work *sometimes* in the office and sometimes at home (say three days at home, two days in the office), and be available for meetings as required.  It doesn't have to be a cut and dried "working from home" or "working in the office."

Sometimes offering an alternate option that is somewhere in the middle can help to break any deadlock.

However, be prepared to talk to a lawyer if necessary, which is why it's important to gather as much documentary evidence as you can.