# I have been signed off sick but my boss doesnt recognise it , can they do that?

Tags: sickness, time-off, scotland

I was recently sexually assaulted at another job that I had to take. On top of suffering from depression and anxiety I have not taken a day off because I was recently off for a kidney infection.  However when I went to my boss I told her what has happening and that the doctor told me that I need to take time off to deal with this (which is right as I feel worse and worse every day).

She then told me that if I don't come into work she will not be able to promise me that I will have job security.  Now this job does not pay that well and they have not went ahead with their promises.  I still came in and have not taken the right dose of my meds because it would make me unfit to drive (I was instructed to take a double dose and I only took my regular dose).

I feel horrible and I can't concentrate and I need some time away to get to terms with all this.

What should I do?  This is my only source of income and I have only been in this position since November last year it is now July.

Comment: Go see the Citizens Advice or a lawyer, if your manager has given you this in writing, many companies get sued, and loose, this type of case. But you have to get good advice with evidence. I am not a lawyer...

Comment: One small thing to clarify: if the doctor only says you should take time off, workplaces in many jurisdictions aren't legally required to abide by a second-hand statement from you. Instead, in most areas you can get a specific form or letter from your doctor saying you are not fit/medically exempt from work (the local proper term for this varies). This can usually be "cannot work at all", or "can work with limited terms (hours, lifting, etc)". This documentation is usually important both to provide to the employer to be clear this is not an idle complaint, and to have for future legal uses.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: [My employer wants me to work from the office against my doctor's orders](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52282/my-employer-wants-me-to-work-from-the-office-against-my-doctors-orders) and [How should I politely turn down a task that my doctor has advised me against?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/74574/how-should-i-politely-turn-down-a-task-that-my-doctor-has-advised-me-against) and [Can they fire me due to being sick?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/122518/can-they-fire-me-due-to-being-sick)

Answer (score 9):

> What should I do?

You should **ask your doctor for a note** where they explain that you need time-off.

A Doctor's note is the strongest evidence you can provide to your employer that you need to take time off for sickness.

If after this your employer still doesn't recognize your time off, then I suggest you contact a Lawyer that can assist you here (case in which you have to document as most as you can from this incident). It would be unwise of your employer to not comply to the Doctor's letter, and hopefully you won't have to take other measures.

Answer (score 2):

I'm like 95% sure that Scotland has laws mandating workplace safety, and getting sexually assaulted while on the job definitely violates that requirement! I would recommend **talking to a lawyer and/or your union representative** about potentially making an industrial relations complaint and/or lawsuit against your employer.

**Just make sure to start documenting everything!** Get everything in writing, if possible; send an email to your boss asking them to confirm their earlier statement regarding potentially getting fired for taking a sick day on your doctor's orders, phrased as though you were asking for clarification. Make sure that your sexual assault was documented, and seriously consider making a police complaint, if you haven't already.